# Merge different sized arrays into a table

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

### Overview

I am currently working with a series of .txt files I am importing into MATLAB.  For simplicity, I'll show my problem conceptually. Obligatory, I'm new to MATLAB (or programming in general).

These .txt files contain data from tracking a ROI in a video (frame-by-frame) with time ('t') in the first column and velocity ('v') in the second as shown below;

```
T1 =           T2 =            etc.

t     v       t     v

0    NaN      0     NaN
0.1  100      0.1   200 
0.2  200      0.2   500
0.3  400      0.3   NaN
0.4  150       
0.5  NaN
```

### Problem

- Files differ in their size, the columns remain fixed but the rows vary from trial to trial as shown in T1 and T2.
- The time column is the same for each of these files so I wanted to organise data in a table as follows;

  ```
  time   v1    v2    etc.

  0      NaN   NaN
  0.1    100   200
  0.2    200   500
  0.3    400   NaN
  0.4    150   0
  0.5    NaN   0
  ```

Note that I want to add 0s (or NaN) to end of shorter trials to fix the issue of size differences.

### Edit

Both solutions worked well for my dataset. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Do you know *a priori* the file whose number of rows is the biggest?

Comment: Only once I've imported them into the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of the `padarray` and `horzcat` functions. They respectively :

1. Pad a matrix or vector with extra data, effectively adding extra 0's or any specified value (`NaN`s work too).
2. Concatenate matrices or vectors horizontally.

First, try to obtain the length of the longest vector you have to concatenate. Let's call this value `max_len`. Once you have that, you can then pad each vector by doing :

```
v1 = padarray(v1, max_len - length(v1), 0, 'post');
% You can replace the '0' by any value you want !
```

Finally, once you have vectors of the same size, you can concatenate them using `horzcat` :

```
big_table = horzcat(v1, v2, ... , vn);
```

Comment: "_The time column is the same for each of these files_" seems to imply all data starts at t=0.0

Comment: Oh gotcha. I was reading it as `NaN` being the placeholder. My bad. More coffee needed!

Answer (score 2):

You could import each file into a `table` using [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) and then use [`outerjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html) to combine the tables in the way that you would expect. This will work if all data starts at `t = 0` or not.

To create a `table` from a file:

```
T1 = readtable('filename1.dat');
T2 = readtable('filename2.dat');
```

Then to perform the `outerjoin` (pseudo data created for demonstration purposes).

```
t1 = table((1:4)', (5:8)', 'VariableNames', {'t', 'v'});

%//     t    v
%//     _    _
%//     1    5
%//     2    6
%//     3    7
%//     4    8

% t2 is missing row 2
t2 = table([1;3;4], [1;3;4], 'VariableNames', {'t', 'v'});

%//     t    v
%//     _    _
%//     1    1
%//     3    3
%//     4    4

%// Now perform an outer join and merge the key column
t3 = outerjoin(t1, t2, 'Keys', 't', 'MergeKeys', true)

%//     t    v_t1    v_t2
%//     _    ____    ____
%//     1    5         1
%//     2    6       NaN
%//     3    7         3
%//     4    8         4
```